# Mopub: Facebook native ads no impression

Tags: android, facebook, mopub, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I integrated mopub native ads successfully on Android project. But Facebook native ads impressions are not counted/triggered. 
Impressions are not triggered in following event listener.

```
nativeAd.prepare(adView);
nativeAd.renderAdView(adView);
nativeAd.setMoPubNativeEventListener(new NativeAd.MoPubNativeEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImpression(View view) {
        Log.w(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "impression");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.w(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "clicked");
    }
});
```

I tested on FacebookNative.java file. Following code is not triggered

```
@Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(final Ad ad) {
            notifyAdImpressed();
        }
```

Please guide, why fb native ads are not counting impressions.